# "What are our numbers?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, expressions, translation

How can I correctly ask a question like "What are our numbers?" meaning what are the number of people in the audience in comparison with number of people in some other audience.

Comment: "What's the head count?" would be one idiomatic way to ask about attendance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How many of us are there here?"
-- Emphasizes the connection between speaker and audience".

"What is the size of this audience?"
-- More impersonal.

"How many are we?"
-- More poetic, less clear about whether "we" are just the audience or some larger group.